# How do I make a free city as the HRE in EU4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm starting as Austria in EU4.  Where is the button (diplomacy option) that lets me make Friesland a free city in the Empire?  Where can I find which HRE members are already free cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the **Common Sense DLC** is required to have these options.

The diplomacy option to create a Free City is under the Emperor Actions tab. Nations are only eligible to become a Free City if:

- there are less than 8 Free Cities in the Empire
- they have a single province, with at least 10 total development. If a Free City takes a second province, it loses its status.
- they are a member of the Holy Roman Empire.
- they are not a subject nation
- they are not an Elector.
- they are at peace.

[image: Diplomatic options]

You can view existing Free Cities using the Imperial Map Mode, where they show up blue. Members show up as green, electors as orange and the Emperor as purple. Provinces owned by non-members are hashed yellow.

[image: Map mode option]

[image: Imperial Map Mode]

Comment: I didn't see the above... then I checked my dlc and realized common sense was required to have the above options.  Thanks and I'll use this when I get the dlc in the winter sale.